# PC communication using name pipes method through LAN cable

Tags: named-pipes

I have a need of implementing 2 windows(MFC) application which need to exchange data over pc over network (connect through LAN cable) with high speed (as fast as possible).

For this purpose, I have create 2 applications which communicate using name pipes. Both application working fine when locate in same pc, or different pc which under same domain (with condition that pc need contain user profile for another pc that it connect to).

However when both pc are connect through network cable over LAN, both application (serve and client) cannot connect to each other. I try set the security attributes before create server's site name pipes, but it still not working well! Any hints or solution?

pipe name: \192.168.0.59\PIPE\TEST_SPEED

Answer (score 1):

You're using named pipes over the network which means named pipes over samba or however Windows do domain networking. It only works when the computers are in the same domain or workgroup.

Why not use sockets instead? It's the standard way to do networking and works wherever you have IP addresses.

Comment: For pc in same workgroup, it cant connect. Is socket method as fast as name pipes?

Comment: Faster, likely. Sockets are how the Internet works, and named pipes over samba is running on sockets under the hood already. Why not just use them directly?